# drupal notification for content type

Tags: notifications, emails

I have a requirement to allow users to subscribe content type. When a new node of the subscribed content type is created, notification mail must be sent. I tried [notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/notify) module but it only allows to subscribe while registration.

Is there any solution for unsigned users to subscribe a content type?

Comment: create a rule for sending mail on node publish.

Comment: "i have requirement to allow users to content type" -To do what with that content type? Would you care to edit it a bit? Or do you want me to do it?

Comment: @Mołot i have requirement to allow users to subscribe content type

Comment: For unsigned users it will be hard - Drupal keeps all user-related data in tables related to, well, users. Unregistered users are one user to the system (uid 0). Probably you will need to use some code from one of the newsletter modules and some from Notify to make this work the way you want it.

Comment: Try this module

https://drupal.org/project/simplenews_content_selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to create a rule that's fired when new content is added and when a user is subscribed to it (check this with a condition). Use the 'Send email' action to send an email to the subscribed users.